# How delete a Website from Google Search Engine?

Tags: web, google-search-console

I want to remove a website from Google Search engine Entirely. The website has 200,000+ posts indexed on google. Can anyone pls telll me that how can I remove it entirely from gooogle as I didn't want a single post of it inddexed in google...

I know how to prevent google bot from indexing my new postst but **how can I remove my previously indexed 2 lac posts?**

I am expecting to get a way through which I can remove my website entirely fron google....

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [No index for an entire site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117152/no-index-for-an-entire-site)

Comment: Also, please avoid using words like *lac* that are not understood globally

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To quickly (but temporarily) remove an entire website from Google, you could use Google Search Console's [Removals](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846) tool. It'll allow you to rapidly hide the website from Google, but it's only a temporary fix until you can add a `noindex` tag (see Sahildeep Singh's answer to do that). To do so, go to the [Removals page](https://search.google.com/u/1/search-console/removals) in the Google Search Console and press the "New Request" button. From there, you can add an entire block of URLs (e.g. `example.com` would block `example.com/xyz`) to be hidden from Google Search.

Comment: If I add the website home page URL then will it remove all the website?

Comment: That's correct. Adding `example.com` and selecting the `Remove all URLs with this prefix` button would remove all derivatives of the URL (e.g. `example.com/abc`, `example.com/def`, `example.com/ghi`, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

If you need to prevent your webpages from being indexed then insert this following meta code :

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Just add this code inside your header component/file